# @DeclareRoles in Scala - annotation argument Array[String] needs to be a constant

Tags: scala, annotations, constants

I'm trying to add the @DeclareRoles annotation to my Scala Web Service.  I declare it using:

**@DeclareRoles({"AuthorizedUser"})**

When I compile, I get:

**type mismatch;

found   : String("AuthorizedUser")

required: Array[String]

@DeclareRoles({"AuthorizedUser"})**

I've then tried to declare a final variable for it:

**final val role: scala.Array[String] = Array("AuthorizedUser")

@DeclareRoles(role)**

But this gets the following error (as expected I think):

**annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: EndPoint.this.role

@DeclareRoles(role)**

I also tried:

**object Constants {

final val role: scala.Array[String] = Array("AuthorizedUser")

}

@DeclareRoles(Constants.role)**

But this generates the same error.

Any idea how I do this in Scala?  How do I create an Array[String] constant for this annotation?

I'm using Scala 2.11.12 with IntelliJ.

Comment: By using a constant ... `@DeclareRoles(Array("AuthorizedUser"))`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez that works.  Thank you.  I was thinking a constant had to be a string literal (i.e "foo").

Comment: A string literal is also a constant, but this annotation requires an array.